# Find last date of previous week using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame as shown below:

```
structure(list(Start_Date = c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "NA", "NA", 
"D6", "D7"), Week = c("W1", "W1", "W1", "W2", "W2", "W3", "W4", 
"W4"), last_date = c(NA, NA, NA, "D3", "D3", "D4", "D4", "D4"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

output is column 'last_date'

What I require ? -I want to find last non-NA date of previous week. If the previous week has only NA date then it should look into previous to previous week and find non-NA date. 
For example - for all dates of W2, the last date would be D3 (last non-NA date of previous week). For W3, it should return D4.
**For W4**, as only last date of W3 is NA, it should look for non-NA date in previous to previous week (i.e. W2) and return D4.

Summarizing, the last date will be most recent non-NA date (not coming from current week)

As my data set is too bulky, I am looking for a data.table solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option (assumes data is ordered already):

```
# Load data.table and convert data.frame to data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# Clean data; "NA" is just a regular character at the moment
df[Start_Date == "NA", Start_Date := NA_character_]

# Step 1: Create a numeric week index
df[, week_nr := .GRP, keyby = Week]
# Step 2: Create a lookup table (lut) for last date for each week
lut <- df[!is.na(Start_Date), last(Start_Date), by = week_nr + 1L]
# Step 3: Use join syntax to "consult" the lut and add a new column
df[, last_dat2 := lut[.SD, on = "week_nr", V1, roll = Inf]]
```

Step 2-3 *could* be compressed to one step:

```
df[, last_dat2 := df[!is.na(Start_Date)
                     ][.SD, 
                       on = .(week_nr < week_nr), 
                       last(Start_Date), 
                       by = .EACHI]$V1]
```

Or a bit more cleanly using `mult=`:

```
df[, last_dat2 := df[!is.na(Start_Date)
                     ][.SD, 
                       on = .(week_nr < week_nr), 
                       Start_Date, 
                       mult = "last"]]
```

Output:

```
   Start_Date Week last_date week_nr last_dat2
1:         D1   W1      <NA>       1      <NA>
2:         D2   W1      <NA>       1      <NA>
3:         D3   W1      <NA>       1      <NA>
4:         D4   W2        D3       2        D3
5:       <NA>   W2        D3       2        D3
6:       <NA>   W3        D4       3        D4
7:         D6   W4        D4       4        D4
8:         D7   W4        D4       4        D4
```

Comment: Hi Sindri..Thank you for the solution. However, I found a miss in your solution. According to your solution, it just moves the pointer  to previous week. If the previous week has just one NA date then it should look into previous to previous week and find out non-NA date. In short, the latest non-NA date (not from current week)

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option is to use `roll=` with `mult=`

```
setDT(DT)[, c("Week", "W") := .(rl <- rleid(Week), rl - 0.1)][, 
    last_dat := df[Start_Date!="NA"][
        .SD, on=.(Week=W), roll=Inf, mult="last", x.Start_Date]
    ]
```

Will be interested to know the dimension and stats of actual dataset to time the diff solutions.

output:

```
   Start_Date Week last_date   W last_dat
1:         D1    1      <NA> 0.9     <NA>
2:         D2    1      <NA> 0.9     <NA>
3:         D3    1      <NA> 0.9     <NA>
4:         D4    2        D3 1.9       D3
5:         NA    2        D3 1.9       D3
6:         NA    3        D4 2.9       D4
7:         D6    4        D4 3.9       D4
8:         D7    4        D4 3.9       D4
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- structure(list(Start_Date = c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "NA", "NA", 
    "D6", "D7"), Week = c("W1", "W1", "W1", "W2", "W2", "W3", "W4", 
        "W4"), last_date = c(NA, NA, NA, "D3", "D3", "D4", "D4", "D4"
        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: I forgot about `mult=` in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the look-up table to join with is created in a different way:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # piping used to improve readability
lut <- DT[, .(Week, fifelse(Start_Date == "NA", NA_character_, Start_Date) %>% zoo::na.locf())][
  , last(V2), by = Week][
    , V1 := shift(V1)][]
DT[lut, on = .(Week),  last_date2 := V1][]
```

> ```
>    Start_Date Week last_date last_date2
> 1:         D1   W1      <NA>       <NA>
> 2:         D2   W1      <NA>       <NA>
> 3:         D3   W1      <NA>       <NA>
> 4:         D4   W2        D3         D3
> 5:         NA   W2        D3         D3
> 6:         NA   W3        D4         D4
> 7:         D6   W4        D4         D4
> 8:         D7   W4        D4         D4
> ```

The look-up table is

```
lut
```

> ```
>    Week   V1
> 1:   W1 <NA>
> 2:   W2   D3
> 3:   W3   D4
> 4:   W4   D4
> ```

created by

- replacing missing `Start_Date` values by previous values (*LOCF* = *Last Observation Carried Forward*),
- which requires to replace the character string `"NA"` by `NA_character` beforehand,
- aggregating by `Week`,
- and shifting (lagging) the values by one week, finally.

Note that the look-up table does not contain any `NA` values (except for the first row, of course) and that the last valid `Start_Date` `D4` of week `W2` has been carried forward to weeks `W3` and `W4`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution, where `ave()` and `split()` are used:

```
df$last_date <- df$last_date <- with(df, ave(na.omit(Start_Date)[cumsum(!is.na(Start_Date))],Week, FUN = function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)],1)))
dfout <- Reduce(rbind,
                lapply(seq(dfs<-split(df,df$Week)), 
                       function(k) {
                         dfs[[k]]$last_date <- ifelse(k==1, NA, unique(dfs[[k-1]]$last_date)); 
                         dfs[[k]]}))
```

such that

```
  Start_Date Week last_date
1         D1   W1      <NA>
2         D2   W1      <NA>
3         D3   W1      <NA>
4         D4   W2        D3
5       <NA>   W2        D3
6       <NA>   W3        D4
7         D6   W4        D4
8         D7   W4        D4
```